# Vue produces "Syntax Error: Assigning to rvalue"

Tags: vue.js

I am not able to solve the following error in my code. How can I fix it?

```
<div class="selector">
  <v-layout>
    <div>
      <v-flex xs2>
        Details
        <v-switch v-model="8"></v-switch>
      </v-flex>
      <div v-if="8" id="app" class="container">
        <v-checkbox>
          Accept Type?
        </v-checkbox>
      </div>
    </div>
  </v-layout>
</div>
```

This results in the error:

> Syntax Error: Assigning to rvalue (1:1856)

Comment: Is this because you are calling your model variable 8? What if you did v-model="eight" and v-if="eight".

Comment: yes.Thank you. The error is resolved.

Comment: You should mark this as resolved then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a follow up if anyone is having a similar problem. It looks like Vue is mapping through the values of this. If it comes across a property that is named as a number like this.8, it throws an error. You should probably avoid numbers and special characters in v-model.

Answer (score 1):

Is this because you are calling your model variable 8?

You should use as below:

// did

`v-model="eight"`

// then use

`v-if="eight"`